# PHP image dimension

Tags: php, image, dimension

How to get width and height of an image?

I have `$variable = 'http://site.com/image.png"`

Want to get width of this image to `$width` and height to `$height`.

Like:
`$variable = 'http://site.com/image.png"`

```
$width = '300'; // image width is 300px
$height = '500'; // height is 500px
```

Thanks.

Comment: anyway, here is a little magic: http://google.com/search?q=PHP+image+dimension

Comment: possible duplicate of [quickest way to dynamically retrieve image dimensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334097/quickest-way-to-dynamically-retrieve-image-dimensions)

Comment: then it shouldn't be an url `http://site.com/image.png` but a filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$variable = 'http://site.com/image.png';
$image    = getimagesize($variable);
$width    = $image[0];
$height   = $image[1];
$type     = $image[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

[getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) function. Maybe it will help you.

Comment: Caveat: the combination of remote FS and image functions can have subtle quirks, e.g. if the remote HTTP server is slow to respond, execution will hang until `getimagesize()` returns (which can be "until HTTP connection times out", which means tens of seconds).

Comment: Certainly you want to cache the results of any image size check you do - if its at all possible.