# PHP + JS: Determine dimensions of an image file

Tags: php, jquery, image, png, jpeg

How can you tell the dimensions of a .jpeg or .png file without opening it?

If it is impossible to determine the dimensions, how can I automatically crop an image?

I am using PHP and JS.

Comment: what you want find image width and height because dimension includes height and width.gd lib is best solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "not opening" it?

Comment: Where do you need the dimensions in PHP or in JS?

Comment: Your question is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334097/quickest-way-to-dynamically-retrieve-image-dimensions - save for the 'not opening' bit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855996/crop-image-in-php

Comment: there is no specific way to automatically crop an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize("img.jpg");
      or

$im=imagecreatefromjpeg("image_testin_1.JPG");
imagetruecolortopalette($im, false, 255);

$w = imagesx($im);//provide width of full page
$h = imagesy($im);//provide height of full page
```